# How can I download a specific Maven artifact from repository to local drive?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

There might be some times that we want to download a specific Maven artifact from repository to local drive.
In my case, I would like to use a third party library published in Maven repository in a particular IDE. However, the IDE I use has no integration support for maven repository yet, therefore the only way to use this library is to download the artifact to my local drive.
I'm a newbie for maven, any suggestions will be very appreciated. Thanks.

**-----UPDATE------**

I learned from other threads and realised I should use maven dependency plugin to download an artifact to local folder. In my case, I need to download google ARCore from maven repository. I search the ARCore at maven repository, and know that:

**Category: com.google.ar, Group:core, version:1.1.0**

So I used the following command line to download it:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.google.ar:core:1.1.0
```

However, it failed to download the artifact, the error message is like:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) com.google.ar:core:jar:1.1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.ar -DartifactId=core -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.ar -DartifactId=core -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Path to dependency:
[ERROR]         1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]         2) com.google.ar:core:jar:1.1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
```

Anyone can give a help? Thanks.

Comment: Also I have the same issue it is confusing :how to download and where to copy for android studio !. I want  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.jar .It is not only resone for manually downloding.Somtime the repository site is not working properly and you could not build your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of the artifact option though:
A string of the form **groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging][:classifier].**
Look at its last (optional) token, [:classifier]. I think That is what you are missing.
try this one,
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.google.ar:core:1.1.0:jar:jar-with-dependencies

Comment: I think your suggestion should be correct. But somehow it still claims that the artifact is missing. Luckily I acquire the artifact from other source. P.S. This library is packed as aar file.